# How to get localeCompare to behave similarly to .sort(), so that all capital letters come first?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of characters I want to sort:

```
const arr = ['z', 'a', 'Z', 'A'];
```

I want the sorted order to be: upper-case characters alphabetically, followed by lower-case characters alphabetically:

```
['A', 'Z', 'a', 'z']
```

This is trivial to accomplish using `.sort()` without any parameters:

```js
const arr = ['z', 'a', 'Z', 'A'];
arr.sort();
console.log(arr);
```

But how could `localeCompare` be used to determine the same relative position of each character? The [caseFirst](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters) option looked promising:

> Whether upper case or lower case should sort first. Possible values are "upper", "lower", or "false" (use the locale's default); the default is "false". This option can be set through an options property or through a Unicode extension key; if both are provided, the options property takes precedence.

But it doesn't appear to do what I want. I've tried many variants:

```js
// Desired result: ['A', 'Z', 'a', 'z']

const arr = ['z', 'a', 'Z', 'A'];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(arr);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { caseFirst: 'upper' }));
console.log(arr);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'case', caseFirst: 'upper' }));
console.log(arr);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { caseFirst: 'upper' }));
console.log(arr);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'kf', { caseFirst: 'upper' }));
console.log(arr);
```

I'd like it to perform similarly to `.sort()` (at least for alphabetical characters), which compares each character's code point:

```js
['A', 'Z', 'a', 'z'].forEach((char) => {
  console.log(char.charCodeAt());
});
```

Of course, I know I can simply avoid `localeCompare` and use `.sort()` without a callback, or use the `charCodeAt` method above:

```js
const arr = ['z', 'a', 'Z', 'A'];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt() - b.charCodeAt());
console.log(arr);
```

But how would I do it using `localeCompare`?

Comment: I will reward a bounty to a good answer.

Comment: There is no _good_ answer as your very well written question demonstrates. The only answer is to filter into two arrays (upper,lower), sort each using `localeCompare()` then `.merge()` then back together.

Comment: Would have been useful to know which features from `localeCompare` you wanted.

Comment: @Kaiido Whichever features that can compare lexicographically, at least for plain alphabetical characters. I don't know what those features are or if they exist - I suspect they don't - but if they do, I'm not picky. I can easily accomplish it without `localeCompare` but was just curious if it's something `localeCompare` could somehow be used for too. It looks much nicer than the conditional operator, and `.sort()` without arguments only works when sorting arrays of strings - not for objects, and not when outside the context of array sorting.

Comment: So... you want to use `localeCompare` just because it *looks* good? You don't actually need anything it does like considering `é` before `f`?

Answer (score -2):

Was able to sort your array lexicographically using this.

```js
const lexicalCompare = (a, b) =>
  a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);

const arr = ['z', 'a', 'Z', 'A'];

console.log(arr.sort(lexicalCompare));
```

Comment: That's the same as no sorter OP said they didn't want. They want to use `localeCompare` (for I don't know what reasons)